# How to pass bitset of any size to a function?

Tags: c++, templates

The following program compiles fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

void foo(std::bitset<10> n)
{
    std::cout << n.size() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::bitset<10> n;
    foo(n);
}
```

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic foo.cpp
$ ./a.out 
10
```

How can I modify the `foo()` function such that it can accept `bitset` of any size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's what [templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) supposed to do. So make `foo` a function template with [non-type template parameter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments):

```
template<std::size_t N>
void foo(std::bitset<N> n)
{
    std::cout << n.size() << "\n";
}
```

then

```
std::bitset<10> n10;
foo(n10);
std::bitset<20> n20;
foo(n20);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `std::bitset<N>` are types, so you can create a template function that accept a generic type

```
template <typename T>
void foo (T n)
 { std::cout << n.size() << "\n"; }
```

Observe that this function will work with not only with all `std::bitset` but also with all types with a `size()` member that return a value that can be send to `std::cout`, as a lot of STL containers (`std::set`, `std::vector`, `std::map`, etc).

So, by example, you can also call `foo()` as follows

```
 std::vector<int> v(20);
 foo(v);
```

This can be good or bad, according to your requirements.

If you want a function that accept **only** a `std::bitset`, so you can follows the solution suggested by songyuanyao: you can explicit `std::bitset` and templatize the dimension.

```
template <std::size_t N>
void foo (std::bitset<N> n)
{ std::cout << n.size() << "\n"; }
```

but, in this case, there is no need to use `size()`; you can use directly `N`

```
template <std::size_t N>
void foo (std::bitset<N>)
{ std::cout << N << "\n"; }
```

If, in addiction, you want that `foo` accept a `std::bitset<N>` with (by example) `N` in a range of values (say `[10,20[`), and you can use C++11, you can use SFINAE and write something as follows

```
template <std::size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<(N >= 10U) && (N < 20U)>::type foo (std::bitset<N>)
 { std::cout << N << "\n"; }
```

Now you have

```
std::bitset<10> n10;
std::bitset<15> n15;
std::bitset<25> n25;

foo(n10);    // compile
foo(n15);    // compile
// foo(n25); // compilation error
```

Answer (score -1):

You also can use `auto`, much less code then template declaration

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

void foo(auto n)
{
    std::cout << n.size() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::bitset<15> n;
    foo(n);
}
```

Comment: I think that template version will give more comprehensible error messages compared to your version.

Comment: Yes it will, but in current task (show size of dynamic bitset), it will work fine.

Comment: This is not standard C++ yet.

Comment: `auto` as a function parameter outside of lambdas is not standard C++ yet unfortunately.

Comment: That's strange because i tried it here cpp.sh/8xzss and it runs fine.

Comment: It's a compiler extension. It's probably going to be adopted as part of Concepts, but it's not in yet.